# Enabling and disabling forms in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created two forms in C#: form1 is the main application and form2 is a logon window. form1 has a button that disable itself and show form2 and form2 has button that enable the main form and closes itself. The problem is when I try to enable form1 using a form2 button (I get "An unhandled exception of type `'System.NullReferenceException'` occurred in Application.exe")

Here is the form1 code:

```
Login  Login = new Login();
Login.Show();
this.Enabled = false;
```

form2(Login) code:

```
(this.Owner as Form1).Enabled = true;  ===> this line gets highlighted
 Close();
```

Comment: Because you don't set the owner property of the `Login` form when you create it, so its null. It doesn't automatically get set just because you open it in one form... Also, don't do this: `Login  Login = new Login();`, its bad practice to name a variable the same as the type you are instantiating, makes it difficult for you to call static methods if needed later without fully qualifying the type.

Comment: If you want to show a form modally (automatically disabling the parent) call ShowDialog instead. Can you explain why you want to disable Form1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx), this will make all other forms (of the same application) inaccessable during the show of the form:

```
using (var login = new Login()) {
    login.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

And you can pass one of the [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) values, as the return code, to pass success or failure to the calling method.

Comment: Pretty sure this is what the OP is trying to achieve

Answer (score 4):

Change this line of code in `form1` from

```
Login.Show();
```

to

```
Login.Show(this);
```

or set owner explicitly before showing like:

```
Login.Owner = this;
Login.Show();
```

Otherwise that login form will not has owner and `this.Owner` will be null leading to `NullReferenceException` when you're trying to access its members.