# Choose file C# and get directory

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to open a file dialog box so the user can choose the location of an access database. Can someone explain how to add a file dialog when a button is clicked and also how to transform the user choice into a string that contains the file directory ( c:\abc\dfg\1234.txt)?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog

Answer (score 27):

As you did not state the technology you use (WPF or WinForms), I assume you use WinForms. In that case, use an [`OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx) in your code. After the dialog was closed, you can get the selected full file name using the `FileName` property.

There is the following example of how to use it on the documentation page I linked above, which I modified slightly as you want the file name, not the stream:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Database files (*.mdb, *.accdb)|*.mdb;*.accdb" ;
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 0;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true ;
    
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    { 
        return;
    }

    string selectedFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    //...
}
```

Comment: _the location of an access database_  (*.mdb or *.accdb) :-) (Also the question talks about a file directory but shows a full pathname)

Comment: @Steve Originally I intended to leave the rest as a trivial exercise to the user, but I fixed it now :-). I guess he wants the file name including the path, which is what the `FileName` property does.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269088/enabling-and-disabling-forms-in-c-sharp) I assume you are using WinForms.
You can use the `OpenFileDialog` Class for this purpose. See the code below which will run on your button `Click` event assuming your button id is `button1`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Access files (*.accdb)|*.accdb|Old Access files (*.mdb)|*.mdb";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       var path = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
}
```

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually fairly simple

```
namespace YourProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string path = "";

        //Declare the File Dialog
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (odf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                path = ofd.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually have a form with button (*button1*)...

At the constructor hook into button1's click event

```
...
button1.Click += button1_Click;
...
```

Then define the handling function and use System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog as you like.

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string oSelectedFile = "";
  System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog oDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
  if (System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK == oDlg.ShowDialog())
  {
    oSelectedFile = oDlg.FileName;

    // Do whatever you want with oSelectedFile
  }
}
```