# Can I let the user select excel file to be imported into Datagridview?

Tags: c#

I found some tutorials to import an excel file but the code contains the file path of an excel file to be imported however I need the user to be able to browse for their desired file, I can't seem to find tutroials for this using C#, I would appreciate it if someone can help me with sample code or point me to a tutorial.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
   conn.ConnectionString = "";

   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
   (
      "SELECT"+
      "FROM [Sheet1$]", conn
       );
   DataSet dsDvds = new DataSet();
   OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
   adapter.Fill(dsDvds);

   dataGridView1.DataSource = dsDvds.Tables[0];
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you save the file first on the file system and then use the code you have. However there are many tutorials for your requirement available over internet.

Comment: chekc this https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Import-data-from-Excel-to-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:
`

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\" ;
fileDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx;";

if(fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string selectedFileName = fileDialog.FileName;
    //...
}`
```

(Code adjusted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31294665/7274172) answer)
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31294665/7274172) and [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/openfiledialog-in-C-Sharp/) link.

Comment: Thanks for your help, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog?view=netframework-4.7.2) for browsing for the file