# How to get directory of an xls file C#

Tags: c#

I need to make a program that reads the columns of an excel. But for that, I need to get the path (directory) of this excel. What prevents me from doing this, is that I didn't want to leave my local directory fixed, because if someone downloads the file on another machine, they will need to change the path.

[image]

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content in posts, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*.

Comment: Write your info in a configuration file and then read it in code. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/store-custom-information-config-file

Comment: Have you considered using an `OpenFileDialog` and let the user choose the file?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Are you just looking for [Choose file C# and get directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31294588)?

Comment: Usually you can copy-paste your code. "The basic [Markdown](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#:~:text=The%20basic%20Markdown%20syntax%20allows,and%20after%20the%20code%20block.) syntax allows you to create code blocks by indenting lines by four spaces or one tab." Just watch that first line it's always the make or break for [Formatting](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked ***How to get directory of an xls file C#***.

As others have pointed out, the file needs to be in a known location and one way to do that is to add the Excel file to your solution and mark it as `Content`, specifying that it should be copied to the output directory. The image below shows how to set these properties.

You *also* seem to be looking for a robust way to make this happen when you [deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/package-and-deploy/) the app for other users. For this, you will need a strategy for making an .msi or .msix that will place this file where it needs to be. **But to answer your basic question the way you asked it** the path in this case can be obtained in this manner. This code will get the path and open the Excel file.

```
// Get the path and open the Excel file
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path =  
        Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), 
            "Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx");

    Console.WriteLine(path);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
}
```

[image]

I should mention that a file in the executing directory can be read but not written (without elevated permissions). If the file *is* user data then refer to the answer that uses an Environment variable:

`var appdata = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If you don't want to your excel files to be stored in your application's directory, you can simply put things in the root of your C: partition. <s>Every windows device is gonna have the C: partition.</s> As the user Lee Taylor has pointed out, it turns out you can have a windows device without the C: partition, although uncommon
2. If you don't mind having your excel files stored in your application's directory, you can get the relative path of your application's directory through`Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

There are other ways but I believe these are the simplest and easiest to do.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/655961/is-it-possible-for-a-windows-installation-to-not-have-the-c-drive

So, not 100% guaranteed to have a c drive.

Comment: Adding files to `c:` is a bad idea, _"The root of C: is protected and you'll get an 'administrator approval' popup if you try to manually create or save a file there"_

Comment: @stuartd so would getting the current logged in user's name, and based on that access the excel files in Documents folder, be a good idea? Or maybe even just AppData/Roaming folder since I know that OneDrive changes your full path directory of Document, Download and Desktop folder.

Comment: Seems to me one way or the other the end user has to specify where the file is and the file name.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to dynamically get the path to a file that is in the same project directory, then the following code works for me -

```
string filePath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + "\\excel\\Prices.xlsx";
```

where "\excel" is the folder in my project and "\Prices.xlsx" the file in the project