# C# load saved JSON files to Listbox and display properties for selected item

Tags: c#, json, winforms, view, listbox

I have saved a list of JSON files stored in a local folder. For example:

**Allen Lex.json**

```
{
    "FirstName": "Allen",
    "LastName": "Lex",
    "Email": "allen.lex",
    "TeamName": "Allen Lex",
    "Password": "allen123",
    "IsActive": "Yes",
    "UserId": 15
}
```

**Eddie Chavo.json**

```
{
    "FirstName": "Eddie",
    "LastName": "Chavo",
    "Email": "eddie.chavo",
    "TeamName": "Eddie Chavo",
    "Password": "eddie123",
    "IsActive": "Yes",
    "UserId": 120
}
```

**First**, I am trying to view all those JSON files to a listbox. **Then**, I want to populate the selected JSON file into a series of textfields for each attribute.

Here's my code in adding/creating a JSON file and save it to the folder:

```
string isActive = chkIsActive.Checked ? "Yes" : "No";

var account = new UserAccount()
{
    FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
    LastName = txtLastName.Text,
    Email = txtEmail.Text,
    TeamName = txtTeamName.Text,
    Password = txtPassword.Text,
    IsActive = isActive,
    UserId = int.Parse(txtUserId.Text)
};
string jsonFilePath = $@"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\Output\" + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text + ".json";

JsonMgr.SerializeObj_ToFile<UserAccount>(account, jsonFilePath);

MessageBox.Show("Successfully added new record", "Added user", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Where I am stuck is reading these JSON files back from the disk so I can display them to a ListBox. Then I want to populate the text fields. Can someone help me with my problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `Json` files stored in a folder and you say you have two goals:

1. **View all those JSON files to a listbox**
2. **Populate the JSON file selected [to] textfields for each attribute.**

I see you are already making a `class` to model the properties from your `Json` files on disk. You are taking a good approach that makes both outcomes easier. You can take the additional step of overriding the `ToString` method to describe how it should display in the `ListBox`.

```
class UserAccount
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    // Format how this record should display in the ListBox
    public override string ToString() => $"User: {FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

The following code uses: `using Newtonsoft.Json` (A NuGet package to be installed). I see you are already familiar with `Json` serialization; this is just one approach. Using `Json` and the model, it's easy to create `UserAccount` class objects and add them to the `Items` collection of the `ListBox`:

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dir = Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location),
                "json");

    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.json"))
    {
        var text = File.ReadAllText(file);
        // Having a model makes it easy to convert the Json.
        var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserAccount>(text);
        // Adding the model to the list will use the "ToString" method to display it.
        listBoxJsonNames.Items.Add(model);
    }
}
```

The code you write in your `ToString` method determines how the data is displayed:

[image: ToString demo in ListBox]

When an item is selected in the `ListBox`, you can simply cast the `SelectedItem` to your model class and use its properties to populate your textboxes:

```
private void listBoxJsonNames_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var model = (UserAccount)listBoxJsonNames.SelectedItem;
    textBoxFirstName.Text = model.FirstName;
    textBoxLastName.Text = model.LastName;
    textBoxUserId.Text = model.UserId;
}
```

[image: Populating text fields]

Comment: Hello. I encountered this error, cant figure out how to fix the path. It says System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\acer\Desktop\VS Trials\NewPipTracker\PipTracker\PipTracker\bin\Debug\json'.'

All of my saved json files is saved in a folder named "Output", it's just one folder after the folder name "debug"

Comment: Usually this is solved by making sure the directory exists, in this case `Output` using `Directory.CreateDirectory(_directory_full_path_)`.

Comment: I tried it this way, but then it doesn't allow me either. Not sure if i did the right thing

`string path = @"C:\Users\acer\Desktop\VS Trials\NewPipTracker\PipTracker\PipTracker\bin\Debug\Output";`

`foreach (var file in Directory.CreateDirectory(path, "*.json"))`

Comment: First try this `using System.Reflection` then `var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);`  _this should give us the first part of the path._

Comment: Sure things, thanks a lot! appreciate the help

Comment: Next get the `Output` path like this. `var outputDir = Path.Combine(dir, "Output");` using the value from the first command.

Comment: Now, if this command gives you an access violation, it's because elevated permissions are often required to write in your executable directory. Is this the issue you're having? `Directory.CreateDirectory(outputDir);`

Comment: Glad to assist!

Comment: In WinForms, the executable starting directory is returned by `Application.StartupPath` . Note that if the application is installed in `Program Files`, you may not have write permission there (you must assume you won't). The common application storage folder, returned by [Application.CommonAppDataPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.commonappdatapath) (`[System Drive]:\ProgramData\[Application Name]`) is often used instead. Or [Application.UserAppDataPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath)

Comment: Your application always has read/write permissions in these specific folders.

Comment: I **agree** with @Jimi. So first, if anyone is having an issue running my code snippets due to where the files are (or _aren't_) try my [working sample on GitHub](https://github.com/IVSoftware/json_to_listbox.git). What I do is copy the json files in the manner I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72418567/5438626). I couldn't tell whether in this case the app's user gets to _create_ new files. That would make it user data. My personal favorite in that case: `var appData = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "{My App}");`